# Shapes "wobble" as they turn - Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a racing game on pygame. It involves a car being able to turn, but when it turns, the car "wobbles". Run the code below and hold down one of the arrow keys if you want to know what I mean. I'm not sure what the problem is, but I would like to keep the line `redcar_pos = list(int(v) for v in pos_red)`
 because it would help a later stage in the game where as soon as the car leaves the track, the game recognises this and does something about it. The "wobble" may not be AS clear on the pygame drawn shape, but is still noticable however I want to use an image for my game (I didn't add the image so it would be easier to run the code) and the image "wobbles" even more. Below is a simple version of the code. I hope someone can help :)

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from pygame.math import Vector2

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WIDTH = 900
HEIGHT = 550
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
REDCAR_ORIGINAL = pygame.Surface((50, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
redangle = 0
redspeed = 2
pos_red = Vector2(200, 200)
vel_red = Vector2(redspeed, 0)

redcar = REDCAR_ORIGINAL
pygame.draw.polygon(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, pygame.Color('dodgerblue'), [(0, 30), (50, 20), (50, 10), (0, 0)])
redrect = redcar.get_rect(center = pos_red)

run = True
while run:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
      redangle += 3
      vel_red.rotate_ip(-3)
      redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
      redrect = redcar.get_rect(center = redrect)
      mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
  elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      redangle -= 3
      vel_red.rotate_ip(3)
      redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
      mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)

  pos_red += vel_red
  redrect = pos_red

  redcar_pos = list(int(v) for v in pos_red)


  screen.fill(pygame.Color('green'))

  screen.blit(redcar, redcar_pos)
  pygame.display.flip()
  clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you create the `redcar_pos` variable because you can just pass the `redrect` as the blit position. You also shouldn't assign the `pos_red` to `redrect` but to its `center` attribute, otherwise `redrect` will be a vector not a pygame.Rect.

In the rotation sections, you can just create new rects and don't need to pass the center coordinates, because `pos_red` (the actual center coordinates) will be assigned to `redrect.center` below each frame.

Here are my suggested changes:

```
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    redangle += 3
    vel_red.rotate_ip(-3)
    redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
    redrect = redcar.get_rect()  # No need to pass the previous center.
    mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    redangle -= 3
    vel_red.rotate_ip(3)
    redcar = pygame.transform.rotate(REDCAR_ORIGINAL, redangle)
    redrect = redcar.get_rect()  # Create a new rect here as well.
    mask_red = pygame.mask.from_surface(redcar)

pos_red += vel_red
redrect.center = pos_red  # Just assign the pos_red to the center.

screen.fill(pygame.Color('green'))

screen.blit(redcar, redrect)  # Blit it at the redrect.topleft coordinates.
```